# Web Apps Telegram, не работают методы setBackgroundColor / setHeaderColor

Tags: reactjs, telegram-bot, web-apps

Методы для изменения цвета не срабатывают, или я что-то делаю не так смотря в докментацию (https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps). Единственное, где заметно изменение цвета - это при открытии клавиатуры, в момент анимации под самим размером окна с клавиатурой.
Отключал все стили, эффект тот же
[image: скрин кода]
[image]
страница[image: стили]

Comment: Можете привести пожалуйста больше информации. Лично я вижу 2 строчки кода, которые написаны вроде правильно. И все. Больше я ничего не знаю о вашем коде. А судя по не очень понятному описанию проблемы, предположу, что если все таки цвет меняется, то проблема в том, что этот фон загораживает какой-то элемент например и по этому вы не видите изменение заднего фона.

Comment: Я исправил код на \ setHeaderColor('secondary_bg_color'); \
И это срабатывает, но только в десктоп версии telegram (на мобильной андроид все остается так же)
Если отключить все файлы стилей, то ничего не меняется, никакой другой цвет не перебивает их

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в моем написании кода
Это работает для меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]